# DynamoDB - Are asynchronous/parallel writes safe?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, race-condition

In a situation where I am only performing UPDATE requests (with no gets) where I do addition operations, would the end result be safe from a race condition?

Here is an example:

```
id: { num: 0 }

id: { num: 1 }

id: { num: 2 }

...

id: { num: 45 }
```

Say all these update operations with a `updateexpression` that adds the `num` attribute gets sent to DynamoDB but asynchronously and without any notion of order, would they still come out safely to the appropriate series end value (which is 1035)?

What would happen if DynamoDB gets two update requests at the same exact time? would one request overwrite another, or would it properly increment, with DynamoDB updating a request one at a time on it's end through an atomic operation?

Would I need to worry about this race condition occurring or does DynamoDB handle this well?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `UpdateItem` operation can be used to implement [atomic counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters). If you're only adding numbers, the order of the operations is irrelevant, there's no race condition.

Comment: Would you explain what this means then from the docs: `An atomic counter would not be appropriate where overcounting or undercounting cannot be tolerated (For example, in a banking application). In this case, it is safer to use a conditional update instead of an atomic counter. `? I require that the number be exact without any over or under-discrepencies by the the end of all update requests. What would I need to do for this? Does conditional updates support the addition operation?

Comment: @TerminatorSkynet if a request to DynamoDB fails in certain ways -- say, with a socket timeout error -- you don't necessarily know whether it failed while the request was on the way to DynamoDB or while the response was en route back to you. Imagine cutting a network cable the instant the "increment" request arrived at DynamoDB.  The update was succeeds, but you saw it fail.  Cut the cable a few milliseconds earlier, and you see exactly the same error, but DynamoDB never saw the request.  Retrying is unsafe, because you can't be sure exactly *when* it failed.  That's what this refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I have a use case where I am maintaining the count of children in a table. 
ex: On parent create do an entry with initial value 0. On each child insert increment the count by 1.

1: Create parent A

id | count
A  | 0

2: Create children increment the id A count by 1

id | count
A  | 1

Case 1: Running script on a terminal with 10 thousand records there was no issue.
Case 2: When we do the Ferfoem operation in lambda(multiple lambdas running concurrently and dong update). Getting the race condition with and without Atomic count [AtomicCount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters)

Atomic count won't ensure the unique value. I moved to the condition update.